# Error in Downloading and Building Source Code from android.source.com

Tags: android-source

I am new to android source code development. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I used official web "source.android" as a guideline for setting up and downloading source code. 
Installed:
1) Python 2.7.10
2) GNU Make 3.82
3) Git latest
4) OpenJDK: sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

***Downloaded following source code:
Build Number: JDQ39, android-4.2.2_r1, Jelly Bean, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7, Nexus 4, Nexus 10***

---

> It downloaded approximately 65GB, is it fine?

---

In guide line provided on source.android.com:
a) HADN'T USED SEPARATE OUTPUT DIRECTORY.
b) HADN'T OPTIMIZED A BUILD ENVIRONMENT
c) WASN'T ABLE TO CONFIGURE: USING AUTHENTICATION
d) AFTER EDITING CODE DON'T KNOW HOW TO VERIFY GIT TAG

When I type command "lunch aosp_arm-eng" after ". build/envsetup.sh" it says:

---

> "build/core/product_config.mk:223: *** Cannot locate config makefile
>   for product "aosp_arm". Stop.
>   ** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_arm'
>   ** Do you have the right repo manifest?"

---

***I have tried instruction sets from various forums but hadn't found any solution. Kindly guide me how to solve this error while building source code.***

Answer (score 0):

> It downloaded approximately 65GB, is it fine?

yes, it's normal.

> "build/core/product_config.mk:223: *** Cannot locate config makefile for product "aosp_arm". Stop. ** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_arm' ** Do you have the right repo manifest?"

There are a few issues that related to the first initialization of the tree.
Try to run "lunch" manually with another "TARGET_PRODUCT". e.x:aosp_arm-eng, aosp_arm64-eng.
these types always exist.